# RoboStack Turtlebot3 teleop

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started to play around with RoboStack https://github.com/RoboStack/ros-noetic. I think is promising but still there is work to do. The installation was not very straight forward in Windows but with some work I was able to figure it out. I was also able to run `turtlesim` without much problems, however turtlebot3, I am able to launch gazebo, start the `teleop` node, check that is publishing correctly, but turtebot3 doesn't move in Gazebo. Unfortunately there is no error I can share, it just doesn't work. If anyone has come across this problem, open to suggestions. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386611/robostack-turtlebot3-teleop/) by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1650 on 2021-09-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-16**:
Just have a look at this question: #q244159, if it is not working then feel free to drop commet.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-16**:
I tried those things. RoboStack is new way to run ROS under Anaconda and is experimental. Thank you for the suggestion.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-09-16**:
I think you should go with ubuntu then.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-16**:
I am experimenting with RoboStack to see if it’s stable to use for education. But yes no issues using turtlebot3 with WSL or Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got it to work, had to start from scratch again:

RoboStack (for ROS Noetic)

```
$ conda create -n robostackenv python=3.8
$ conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
$ conda config --env --add channels robostack
$ conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
```

$ conda install -c robostack ros-noetic-desktop-full

on Windows, install Visual Studio 2017 or 2019 with C++ support
see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation?view=msvc-160

```
$ conda install vs2019_win-64

$ conda deactivate robostackenv
$ conda activate robostackenv
```

Turtlebot3 installation:

```
$ conda install -c robostack ros-noetic-turtlebot3
$ conda install -c robostack ros-noetic-turtlebot3-gazebo
$ conda install -c robostack ros-noetic-turtlebot3-fake
```

Notice that the installation to work:

```
$ conda install -c robostack ros-noetic-desktop-full
```

For some reason yesterday it was working `conda install ros-noetic-desktop-full` but not anymore.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0